# Import python package with shared library

Tags: python, python-import, bpy

I have compiled [Blender as a python module](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3AIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule):

```
ant@asus:~$ ls -l /home/ant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bpy/
drwxrwxr-x 3 ant ant     4096 Jun  6 14:44 2.79
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ant ant 64221200 Jun  6 14:44 bpy.so
```

If I run python from package folder - import works fine:

```
ant@asus:~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bpy/$ python3
>>> import bpy
Color management: using fallback mode for management
>>> dir(bpy)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', 
'__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 
'app', 'context', 'data', 'ops', 'path', 'props', 'types', 'utils']
```

But normal import gives empty module:

```
ant@asus:~$ python3
>>> import bpy
>>> dir(bpy)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', 
'__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

I've tried to add file

```
__init__.py
```

with different content:

---

```
import bpy

ant@asus:~$ python3
>>> dir(bpy)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', 
'__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'bpy']
>>> dir(bpy.bpy)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', 
'__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'bpy']
```

---

```
import os,ctypes
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
libpath = os.path.join(basedir, 'bpy.so')
dll = ctypes.CDLL(libpath)
print(dll)

ant@asus:~$ python3
>>> import bpy
<CDLL '/home/ant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bpy/bpy.so', handle d06750 at 0x7ff30917deb8>
>>> dir(bpy)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__',             
'__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'basedir', 
'ctypes', 'dll', 'libpath', 'os']
>>> dir(bpy.dll)
['_FuncPtr', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', 
'__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', 
'__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
'__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', 
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 
'_func_flags_', '_func_restype_', '_handle', '_name']
```

---

This variant seems almost working, but gives a lot of errors from blender:

```
from . import bpy

ant@asus:~$ python3
>>> import bpy
Color management: using fallback mode for management
RNA_string_set: OperatorProperties.data_path not found.
RNA_string_set: OperatorProperties.value not found.
...
```

There were also a lot of attempts to change PYTHONPATH, sys.path and so on.

---

Finally, using strace, I've found the solution - just rename

```
bpy.so -> __init__.so
```

This works, but looks too hacky.
So, how should it be done in the right way?